# What's the fastest way to compare two arrays of objects and extracting the differing objects?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

Assume I have a Student structure

```cpp
struct Student
{
    int id;
    std::string name;
    int age;
    float dob; // date of birth in seconds, this is just for simplicity's sake
};
```

And I have two different arrays of `Student`s (I open, read and parse two different text files)

```cpp
Student arr1[FIRST_ARR_SIZE];
Student arr2[SECOND_ARR_SIZE];
```

now, my problem is that I want to compare the two arrays and every `Student` object that exists in one array but doesn't exist in the other array should be stored in

```cpp
Student output_arr1[]; // Student objects that only exist in arr1
Student output_arr2[]; // Student objects that only exist in arr2
```

Things to consider:

1. I do not care what exactly was different - all I care about is that this object is not **exactly** present in the other array. (Even if the difference is literally just one bit, that's enough for me to consider it unique)
2. I don't particularly care about memory usage, just want it to run as fast as possible
3. This is NOT simply an equality check. I want the individual objects that differ to be stored.

The only two solutions I could think of, off of the top of my head, are:

1. the O(N*M) brute force solution (i.e., check every combination from arr1 and arr2).

```cpp
for (Student s : arr1) {
    // do stuff
    for (Student s : arr2) {
        // do stuff
    }
    // do stuff
}
```

Obviously this is not good at all.

Or, a much better solution for large-ish (tens / hundreds of thousands) N and M (which is true in my case),

2. Sort it over the id or something and then go over the two arrays in just one two-pointer loop and linearly compare the objects pointed to in both arrays by the two pointers for equality, which would be O(NlogN + MlogM + max(N, M))

I was wondering if there were any clever algorithms to do this even quicker than those two?

Comment: A hash set difference gives you O(N+M). `std::unordered_set`, for example. Diff it twice, one way or the other. Still O(N+M) altogether.

Comment: First of all, please don't tag irrelevant languages (like the C language tag you added to a C++ language question). Then for a set intersection use [`std::set_itersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).  Lastly, unless this is for some kind of so-called "competition" site or similar, complexity is rarely an issue.

Comment: This is exclusive-or (xor), `A ⊕ B = C`.

Comment: Is there a need for this to be very efficient?  Or is development time the concern (example, your finishing date)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don’t want the intersection. And this is not a competition, and it is an issue.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don’t care about development time, this can take a couple of days and I would be fine. I just want it to run very quickly.

Comment: @user362461 -- *I don’t want the intersection* -- Then you may be looking for [std::set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference).

Comment: *This is NOT simply an equality check. I want the individual objects that differ to be stored.* -- Your `Student` object contains a `std::string`.  You have no choice but to do an equality check.

Comment: `for (Student s : arr1) { for (Student s : arr2)` -- This should be: `for (Student& s : arr1) { for (Student& s : arr2)` to eliminate the copying of the object on every iteration.

Comment: Does the first comment answer your question or do you have additional questions? I would upvote the first comment as correct and complete answer.

Comment: And ultimately if you have to compare the contents of the two arrays in those loops using the same identifier in both loop's range-declaration is not recommended.

Comment: *"This is NOT simply an equality check."* -- How do you see this being different than an equality check? Given `Student a;` and `Student b;`, how could you have `a.id == b.id`, `a.name == b.name`, `a.age == b.age`, and `a.dob == b.dob` but not have these objects be the same for your comparison? *Or did you mean something else by "equality check"?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear time, linear space:

Put everything from the smaller array in a hash.

Parse the large array. For each element in the large array:

- If it is in the hash, delete it since it's in both
- If it isn't in the hash, add it to your output

At the end, everything remaining in the hash is only in the smaller array, so add those to the output as well.

Comment: This is nice, but then I can't tell which unique students belonged to which input files. I guess I can just do this twice and switch around the data.

Comment: @user362461 no need to do it twice. Just store the stuff left in the map separately from the list you build as you parse it.